# Projection matrices inequalitites

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive matrices. Furthermore, let $\Pi$ be a projector onto the positive eigen space of $(A-B)$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\Pi(A-B)\Pi >0.
\end{equation}
Then is it true that $\Pi(\log A -\log B)\Pi\geq 0$?